# How to protect against shell injection and blind timing on Windows IIS using web.config?

Tags: security, iis, web, web-config

I used Vega scanner to test my web application and it found some Shell Injection vulnerabilities that can be found by entering commands like these:

```
GET /http:/mywebsite.com/?s="%20%3B%20/bin/sleep%2031%20%3B 

GET /http:/mywebsite.com/http:/http:/mywebsite.com/?s="%20%3B%20/bin/sleep%2031%20%3B
```

I'm running Windows Server with IIS and PHP. A portion of my web.config file is here:

```
        <requestFiltering>
            <denyUrlSequences>

                <add sequence="module" />
                <add sequence="engine" />
                <add sequence="tpl(\.php" />
                <add sequence="profile" />
                <add sequence="Root" />
                <add sequence="Tag" />
                <add sequence="Template" />
                <add sequence="Repository" />
                <add sequence="code-style" />
                <add sequence="GET /?p=/./" />
                <add sequence="/?p=/./" />
                <add sequence="/?" />
                <add sequence="/?p=/./ HTTP/1.1" />
                <add sequence="/bin/sleep" />
                <add sequence="sleep" />
                <add sequence="bin" />
                <add sequence="{" />
                <add sequence="}" />
                <add sequence=";" />
                <add sequence="|" />
                <add sequence="~" />

            </denyUrlSequences>
            </requestFiltering>
```

What I'm trying to do is block these types of queries from being used by using the web.config file. What I have above should be blocking the malicious queries, but it appears to not be working even after updating the web.config and rescanning. Could anyone give me advice on how to proceed please? Thank you very much!

Comment: These look like false positives, possibly triggered by a slow response from your server making the scanner think that its `sleep` command has succeeded. If you are on Windows you will not have a `/bin/sleep`. Additionally, blacklisting is rarely the way to go - there are usually other ways to construct the same command.

Answer (score 0):

try using denyQueryStringSequences since in this case the payload based on your example is coming on the Query not on the segments, for example (and adding the segment as well just incase)

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <hiddenSegments>
                <remove segment="bin" />
                <add segment="bin" />
            </hiddenSegments>
            <denyQueryStringSequences>
                <add sequence="/bin" />
            </denyQueryStringSequences>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```